# Possibility of flipping the role of Master & Slave for a group

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-master-uri, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Scenario**

I have multiple bots running `rtabmap`. They are their own `ROS master` and their is no slave (party of 1). Each bot is *publishing* topics but there are no connected `ROS` machines *subscribing* to this data.

**Question**

If connected to the same wifi network how can I have a third party `ROS` box listen to the topics from each individual ROS bot's topics?

**Note**

I realize I'm somewhat flipping the idea of Master / Slave communication, the reason being that I'm limited to the software only allowing *one* node of `rtabmap` to be present per `ROS master`.

For those interested there is a small discussion leading up to this question which can be followed on [the official rtabmap forum](http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Idea-for-allowing-loop-closures-on-multiple-maps-online-td1532.html).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239249/possibility-of-flipping-the-role-of-master-&-slave-for-a-group/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have one `rtabmap` per slave (i.e., each robot is a ROS slave), and a ROS master running on a remote computer. You would have to put `rtabmap` nodes in different namespaces (e.g., `/robotA/rtabmap`, `/robotB/rtabmap`, etc) to make sure that topics from multiple robots are not published on the same topic name (e.g., `/robotA/mapData`, `/robotB/mapData`, etc...). You would also need to set `tf_prefix` for the [robot state publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) (or TF static transforms) and also for `rtabmap` nodes to have a different TF tree for each robot.

If you prefer having multiple ROS masters, you may want to take a look at the [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) package.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1